# Use Chrome Device management for kiosk style app deployment

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to use Chrome Management Console to deploy kiosk-style devices at a location.

First of all, should I even be investing in kiosk Chrome Apps? [As they are being deprecated](https://developers.chrome.com/apps/migration)?  They don't list a replacement for `kiosk_enabled` so maybe this is a folly.

I have two basic use cases:

1) Static devices that will simply display a full-screen webpage. My hope was that I could remotely specify that webpage on a per device basis, since they will vary slightly: e.g. `website.com/node/:id`. What's the easiest way to achieve this?

2) A more traditional Kiosk that would start at a login page and go from there. This seems like a decent use-case for the `Chrome Kiosk App`. I've learned about the meta-tags necessary to identify a kiosk app. But do I have to upload it to the Chrome Web Store or is there an easier way to deploy it?

Any guidance in general would be appreciated.  Thanks.